# How can i share a web app through vscode that is running locally on xampp?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A'm guessing that if "localhost:80" leads me to "http://localhost/dashboard/" i just need to find the "localhost:number" that leads me to my project but idk how to do it. snippet:[image]

Answer (score 0):

simply  [create a virtual host with xampp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Wo9ZvBMUIU) and you can share your app as you can see in the image above